# Is using one generic method or multiple overloaded methods more appropriate?

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I am working on a project where I will be working with many types of mathematical values, such as fractions, decimal numbers, and mathematical constants (i.e., pi, Euler's number).

I have created an abstract base class, from which each of those types will inherit, with this code.

```
public abstract class MathValue
{
    public abstract double Value { get; set; }

    protected bool irrational;

    public virtual bool IsIrrational
    {
        get { return this.irrational; }
    }

    public virtual T ToValueType<T>(bool ignoreConstraints) where T : MathValue;

    public abstract MathValue Add<TParam>(TParam val) where TParam : MathValue;
    public abstract MathValue Subtract<TParam>(TParam val) where TParam : MathValue;
    public abstract MathValue Multiply<TParam>(TParam val) where TParam : MathValue;
    public abstract MathValue Divide<TParam>(TParam val) where TParam : MathValue;
}
```

However I am now questioning whether it is appropriate to use generic methods here, or if I should replace those methods with overloaded methods in each of the derived classes.

Which would be more appropriate in this case?

Comment: Are your overloads going to do the same thing, or do you add the numbers differently if you happen to be adding PI vs adding Euler's number?  If you don't care, just accept a `MathValue` (it doesn't even need to be generic).  If you need to do something different (which doesn't seem to apply to this case) then have different overloads.

Comment: I think to be able to understand your question better, a sample implementation you have envisioned would help. As @Servy mentioned, do you want an implementation "Add" method to only allow adding of a MathValue that is the same type as the implementing class?

Comment: They will have different behavior. For example, when I add a simple numeric value to a fraction, I want to create an improper fraction rather than converting to a decimal. The goal is to use the MathValue objects as coefficients and exponents in mathematical expressions.

Comment: I will add implementation code shortly for more clarity, I'm on mobile at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I generally feel that overloads are best for scenarios where you need to customize functionality based on a type, but generics are good for functionality that is not type dependent and shared across types.

A good example of an overload class that does different things based on input parameters is the static `Convert` class methods, such as `ToInt32` which has something like 32 overloads.

A good example of a generic class that does the same thing for any type is `List<T>` which will let you put any type in a List in a strongly-typed way, acting the same way for any type T.

An example of returning `ToString()` values:

If I want to output the `ToString()` DIFFERENTLY for each type, I'd use different overloads (or even different classes) for the different parameter types:

```
public class MyMathClass
{
    public string GetToString(int myValue)
    {
        return "My Int: " + myValue;
    }

    public string GetToString(double myValue)
    {
        return "My Double: " + myValue;
    }
}
```

If I want to output ToString for ANY object, I might not use generics since any object has a `ToString()` method... However for the sake of my example I will:

```
public class MyMathClass<T>
{
    public void GetToString<T>(T myValue)
    {
        return myValue.ToString();
    }
}
```